# Stuck on learnpython.org exercise using JSON

Tags: python

http://www.learnpython.org/Serialization_using_JSON_and_pickle

Here are the instructions:

The aim of this exercise is to print out the JSON string with key-value pair "Me" : 800 added to it.

And below is the starting code, which we should modify.

```
#Exercise fix this function, so it adds the given name and salary pair to the json it returns
def add_employee(jsonSalaries, name, salary): 
    # Add your code here

    return jsonSalaries 

#Test code - shouldn't need to be modified
originalJsonSalaries = '{"Alfred" : 300, "Jane" : 301 }'
newJsonSalaries = add_employee(originalJsonSalaries, "Me", 800)
print(newJsonSalaries)
```

I'm completely lost. The JSON lesson was brief, at best.  The issue I seem to be running in to here is that `orginalJsonSalaries` is defined as a string (containing all sort of unnecessary symbols like brackets.  In fact, I think if the single quotes surrounding its definition were removed, `originalJsonSalaries` would be a dictionary and this would be a lot easier.  But as it stands, how can I append `"Me"` and `800` to the string and still maintain the dictionary-like formatting?

And yes, I'm very very new to coding. The only other language I know is tcl.

EDIT:

OK, thanks to the answers, I figured out I was being dense and I wrote this code:

```
import json
#Exercise fix this function, so it adds the given name and salary pair to the json it returns
def add_employee(jsonSalaries, name, salary):
    # Add your code here
    jsonSalaries = json.loads(jsonSalaries)
    jsonSalaries["Me"] = 800
    return jsonSalaries 

#Test code - shouldn't need to be modified
originalJsonSalaries = '{"Alfred" : 300, "Jane" : 301 }'
newJsonSalaries = add_employee(originalJsonSalaries, "Me", 800)
print(newJsonSalaries)
```

This does not work. For whatever reason, the original dictionary keys are formatted as unicode (I don't know where that happened), so when I print out the dictionary, the "u" flag is shown:

```
{u'Jane': 301, 'Me': 800, u'Alfred': 300}
```

I have tried using `dict.pop()` to replace the key ( `dict("Jane") = dict.pop(u"Jane")` ) but that just brings up `SyntaxError: can't assign to function call`

Is my original solution incorrect, or is this some annoying formatting issue and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 4):

The [page you linked to](http://www.learnpython.org/Serialization_using_JSON_and_pickle) says exactly how to do this:

> In order to use the json module, it must first be imported:
>
> ```
> import json
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> To load JSON back to a data structure, use the "loads" method. This method takes a string and turns it back into the json object datastructure:
>
> ```
> print json.loads(json_string)
> ```

They gave you a string (`jsonSalaries`). Use `json.loads` to turn it into a dictionary.

Comment: Turn the JSON into a dictionary, add the `"Me"` and `800` values into the dictionary, then convert the dictionary back to a JSON string.  If you aren't sure how to add the values into the dictionary, try printing the dictionary to see what it looks like.  Good luck and have fun.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty dumb there. However, the "easy" solution I had does not work. The dictionary keys are formatted as unicode so when I print it, the 'u' flag is shown. I'm showing my code and the results as an edit to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Your last question is a new question, but... When you print a dictionary like that you are just using the fact that python is nice enough to show you the contents of its variables in a meaningful way. To print the dictionary in your own format, you would want to iterate through the keys and print the key and value:

```
for k in newJsonSalaries:
    print("Employee {0} makes {1}".format(k, newJsonSalaries[k]))
```

There are other problems in your code....

It is weird to load the JSON inside the add employee function. That should be separate...

Also, in your `add_employee()` function you are hardwired always to add the same values of `Me` and `800` instead of using the `name` and `salary` variables that are passed in, so that line should be:

```
jsonSalaries[name] = salary
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
import json
def add_employee(jsonSalaries, name, salary):
    # Add your code here
    jsonSalaries = json.loads(jsonSalaries)
    jsonSalaries[name] = salary
    jsonSalaries = json.dumps(jsonSalaries)
    return jsonSalaries

#Test code - shouldn't need to be modified
originalJsonSalaries = '{"Alfred" : 300, "Jane" : 301 }'
newJsonSalaries = add_employee(originalJsonSalaries, "Me", 800)
print(newJsonSalaries)
```

Add this before return jsonSalaries:

```
jsonSalaries = json.dumps(jsonSalaries)
```